# Why does the file async API block

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, microsoft-metro

I am writing a simple metro app. However, the API blocks when accessing files. By blocking, I mean the programs waits forever. Creating/opening a file or folder should take at most a few seconds. In this case, it takes forever.

When I run the program, it never comes back from OnTest. Is it what you get.
I understand .Wait will wait for the creation of files and folders to finishe. Maybe that's not great design. However, that's not the point.

My question is:

- Do you get the same behavior (blocks the program forever)
- Is it what's supposed to happen or is it a bug in WinRT? (I am using the consumer preview)
- If that's the expected behavior, why does it take forever?

Here is the XAML code:

```
<Button Click="OnTest">Test</Button>
```

Here is the C# code:

```
 private async void OnTest(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var t = new Cache("test1");
            t = new Cache("test2");
            t = new Cache("test3");
        }
        class Cache
        {
            public Cache(string name)
            {
                TestRetrieve(name).Wait();
            }
            public static async Task TestRetrieve(string name) 
            {
                StorageFolder rootFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                var _folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(name, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                var file = await _folder.CreateFileAsync("test.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            }
        }
```

It blocks on the second call to new Cache("test2");

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have not attempted to run your program or reproduce your problem, but I can make an educated guess as to what is going on.

Suppose you wrote yourself the following to-do list:

- Put a letter to mom in the mailbox.
- Set the alarm to wake me up as soon as I've read her reply.
- Go to sleep.
- Check the mailbox for the reply.
- Read the reply.

Now do everything on that list strictly in order from top to bottom. What happens?

The problem is not with the post office or with mom; they are picking up the letter you put in the mailbox, sending it to mom, mom is writing her reply and the post office is bringing it back to you. The problem is that you never get to the fourth step because you only can start the fourth step *after* you complete the *fifth* step and the alarm wakes you up. You'll sleep forever because *you are essentially waiting for your future self to wake your present self up*.

> Eric, Thank you for the explanation.

You're welcome.

> However, I am still confused as to why my code does not work.

OK, let's break it down. What does your program *really* do? Let's simplify:

```
void M()
{
    Task tx = GetATask();
    tx.Wait();
}
async Task GetATask()
{
    Task ty = DoFileSystemThingAsync();
    await ty;
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

First off: *what is a task*?  A task is an object that represents (1) a job to be done, and (2) a delegate to the *continuation* of the task: the thing that needs to happen *after* the task is done.

So you call GetATask. What does it do? Well, the first thing it does is it makes a Task and stores it in ty. That task represents the job "start some operation on the disk, and notify the I/O completion thread when it is done".

What is the *continuation* of that task?  What has to happen after that task is *done*?  DoSomethingElse needs to be called. So the compiler transforms the *await* into a bunch of code that tells the task to ensure that DoSomethingElse is called when the task is done.

The moment that the continuation of the I/O task has been set, *the method GetATask* returns a task to the caller. *What task is that?* This is a *different* task than the task that got stored into ty. The task that is returned is the task that represents the job *do everything that the method GetATask needs to do*.

What is the continuation of that task?  We don't know! That is up to *the caller of GetATask* to decide.

OK, so let's review. We have two task objects. One represents the task "go do this thing on the file system". It will be done when the file system does its work. It's continuation is "call DoSomething". We have a second task object that represents the job "do everything in the body of GetATask". It will be done *after the call to DoSomethingElse returns*.

Again: the first task will be *complete* when the file I/O succeeds. When that happens, the file I/O completion thread will send a message to the main thread saying "hey, that file I/O you were waiting for is done. I am telling you this because it is now time for you to call DoSomethingElse".

But the main thread *is not examining its message queue*. Why not?  Because **you told it to synchronously wait until everything in GetATask, including DoSomethingElse, is complete**. But the *message* that is telling you *to run DoSomethingElse now* cannot be processed *because you are waiting for DoSomethingElse to be complete*.

Now is it clear?  You are telling your thread to wait until your thread is done running DoSomethingElse **before** you check to see if "please call DoSomethingElse" is in the queue of work to be performed on this thread! You are waiting until you *have read the letter from mom*, but *the fact that you are waiting synchronously means that you are not checking your mailbox to see if the letter has arrived*.

Calling Wait is obviously wrong in this case because you are waiting for *yourself to do something in the future*, and that's not going to work. But more generally, calling Wait **completely negates the entire point of being async in the first place**.  Just don't do that; it doesn't make any sense to say both "I want to be asynchronous" and "but I want to synchronously wait".  Those are opposites.

Comment: Eric, Thank you for the explanation. However, I am still confused as to why my code does not work. It seems the internal code for file and folder is doing some strange thing I am not aware of. If you have a chance, please try my code. I'd be interested to know if it behaves the way you think it should.

Comment: Eric, I understand deadlocks would be a problem. However, it my case, all three tasks work on independent folders. In other words, the completion of one task does not affect other tasks. Beside, they run one after the other. So, how is your point relevant to this example?

Comment: @user380719: My analogy is completely relevant to your situation. In the analogy, "your mom" is the file system and "mail" is the message queue of your thread. Your mom -- the file system -- has sent you a letter saying that the work is done, and you have told yourself to *go to sleep until you've checked the mail and gotten the response*. That doesn't make any sense.  I've updated my answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I assume this would not deadlock with a threadpool synchronizationcontext. i.e. the rule is **never call .Wait on a UI thread**

Comment: Adrian: Got it: the task signals it is done using a UI message. But calling Wait prevents pumping messages. Your point is most helpful!

Comment: Adrian: you really nailed it. The fact that it's a UI thread is key. If you want to post your own answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: It's not just the UI thread. I [recommend](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) a stronger rule: never call `Wait` (or `Result`) in an asynchronous code base. The same deadlock situation would occur in other situations, e.g., ASP.NET (even though there are two different threads in that situation, they would still deadlock), or the exclusive thread pool scheduler in .NET 4.5...

Answer (score 7):

You're using `Wait()` in the constructor of the Cache class. That's going to block until whatever is currently executing asynchronously has finished.

This is not the way to design this. Constructors and async do not make sense. Perhaps a factory method approach like this would work better:

```
public class Cache
{
    private string cacheName;

    private Cache(string cacheName)
    {
        this.cacheName = cacheName;
    }

    public static async Cache GetCacheAsync(string cacheName)
    {
         Cache cache = new Cache(cacheName);

         await cache.Initialize();

         return cache;
    }

    private async void Initialize()    
    {   
            StorageFolder rootFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;   
            var _folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(this.cacheName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);   
            var file = await _folder.CreateFileAsync("test.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
   }
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(Cache.GetCacheAsync("cache1"), Cache.GetCacheAsync("cache2"), Cache.GetCacheAsync("cache3"));
```

Comment: Drew, maybe my design is not great. But that's not my question. My question is why does it block forever?

Comment: My first paragraph explains that. If you switch to my implementation and await the Task.WhenAll you are no longer blocking.

Comment: Drew, thanks for the clarification. I am still confused though. I agree it will block until the files and folder are created. So I expected the constructor to block for maybe one second or two. However, it blocks forever as if the file system was somehow locked. Is it the way it's supposed to be?

Comment: If you're still using your original code, the reason is probably because you've defined the async method TestRetrieve so that returns a Task. Try just changing your TestRetreive method to have a void return type to see if that helps. Then you would also need to change to use await in your constructor and that's really why you should just change the design to what I'm recommending to fit more cleanly into the async model.

Comment: Drew, your code works. So I will use your method. I am still confused why my original code does not work though.

Comment: The deadlock is because `TestReceive` is trying to resume on the UI thread, but the UI thread is blocked on `TestReceive`. I recommend you read my [async intro post](http://tinyurl.com/7ljlmt3) which explains the "context" that `async` methods use. In that post I explain some "recommended best practices" such as calling `ConfigureAwait` whenever possible, returning `Task` instead of `void` whenever possible, etc. Also see [this MSDN forum post](http://tinyurl.com/cespfxs) and Stephen Toub's [Zen of Async](http://tinyurl.com/7mratbg) where he actually demos this exact deadlock situation.

Comment: Good point @StephenCleary, I didn't even unwind all the way back to the fact that he was binding this to the button click. My change to the design and the await on the WhenAll cleared this up indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
TestRetrieve(name).Wait();
```

You're telling it to block specifically by using the `.Wait()` call.

Remove the `.Wait()` and it shouldn't block anymore.

Comment: I want to wait, not block. It would be OK to wait a little bit. However, the program blocks _forever_...

Comment: Because `Wait` does not allow other tasks to run. Even if those other tasks are tasks your thing needs in order to finish. To let other tasks run while waiting, use `await`.

Comment: Raymond, are you saying it is expected behavior that the program will block forever? If this is the case, I bet a lot of .NET developers will be surprised.

Comment: I think Raymond means that `Wait` does not allow other tasks to run *on that thread*. And yes, this has already tripped up several people, but if you allow `async` to grow naturally through your code base, you will end up with no calls to `Wait` (or `Result`) at all.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers provide very thorough explanations of why it blocks and code examples of how to make it not block, but these many be 'more information' than some users understand. Here is a simpler 'mechanics oriented' explanation..

The way the async/await pattern works, each time you await an async method, you are "attaching" that method's async context to the current method's async context. Imagine await as passing in a magic hidden paramater "context".  This context-paramater is what allows nested await calls to attach to the existing async context. (this is just an analogy...the details are more complicated than this)

If you are inside an async method, and you call a method synchronously, that synchronous method doesn't get that magic hidden async context paramater, so it can't attach anything to it. It's then an invalid operation to create a new async context inside that method using 'wait', because the new context does not get attached to your thread's existing top-level async context (because you don't have it!).

Described in terms of the code-example, the TestRetrieve(name).Wait(); is not doing what you think it's doing. It's actually telling the current thread to re-enter the async-activity-wait-loop at the top. In this example, this is the UI-thread, which is called your OnTest handler. The following picture may help:

UI-thread context looks like this...

```
UI-Thread ->
    OnTest
```

Since you didn't have a connected chain of await/async calls all the way down, you never "attached' the TestRetrieve async context to the above UI-Thread async chain. Effectively, that new context you made is just dangling off in nowhere land. So when you "Wait" the UIThread, it just goes right back to the top.

For async to work, you need to keep a connected async/await chain from the top-level synchronous thread (in this case it's the UI-thread doing this) through all async actions you need to do. You can't make a constructor async, so you can't chain an async context into a constructor. You need to construct the object synchronously and then await TestRetrieve from outside. Remove the 'Wait' line from your constructor and do this...

```
await (new Cache("test1")).TestRetrieve("test1");
```

When you do this, the 'TestRetrieve' async context is properly attached, so the chain looks like this:

```
UI-Thread ->
    OnTest ->
        TestRetrieve
```

Now the UI-thread async-loop-handler can properly resume TestRetrieve during async completions and your code will work as expected.

If you want to make an 'async constructor', you need to do something like Drew's GetCacheAsync pattern, where you make a static Async method which constructs the object synchronously and then awaits the async method. This creates the proper async chain by awaiting and 'attaching' the context all the way down.